# Delphi: Update multiple fields of a SQLite record

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi, sql-update, where-clause

I am using the following code to update multiple fields of a specific SQLite record (WONumber = Work Order Number)

```
  aFDQuery.SQL.Clear;
  with aFDQuery.SQL do
    begin
      BeginUpdate;
      try
        Add('update EVENTS set (SITENAME, FILENAME, PARTS, DATERECEIVED, DATECONVERTED, REMINDER, INCOMPLETE)');
        Add('values (:site, :file, :parts, :received, :converted, :reminder, :incomplete) where (WONUMBER = :number)');
      finally
        EndUpdate;
      end;
  end;

  aFDQuery.Params.ParamByName('number').AsInteger         := Number;
  aFDQuery.Params.ParamByName('site').AsString            := ShortSiteName;
  aFDQuery.Params.ParamByName('file').AsString            := FileName;
  aFDQuery.Params.ParamByName('parts').AsString           := Parts;
  aFDQuery.Params.ParamByName('received').AsDateTime      := DateReceived;
  aFDQuery.Params.ParamByName('converted').AsDateTime     := DateConverted;
  aFDQuery.Params.ParamByName('reminder').AsBoolean       := Reminder;
  aFDQuery.Params.ParamByName('incomplete').AsBoolean     := Incomplete;

  aFDQuery.ExecSQL;
  DBConnection.Commit;
```

But I get the following error

```
Error ESQLiteNativeException: while updating Tracking SQLite with: [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: near "values": syntax error
```

Any suggestion ?
What's wrong with that syntax?
Thanks

Comment: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-update/

Comment: `Update EVENTS set sitename = :sitename, filename = :filename...`

Comment: Thank you NolaSpeaker. This is saving my day. Be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not valid SQL. The [`update`](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) syntax goes as follows:

```sql
update events set 
  sitename      = :site,
  filename      = :file,
  parts         = :parts, 
  datereceived  = :received, 
  dateconverted = :converted, 
  reminder      = :reminder,
  incomplete    = :incomplete
where wonumber = :number
```

This is standard SQL syntax, that is uniformly implemented across databases.

Comment: Thank you GMB. NolaSpeaker already gave me the right syntax